# MIME type wont change for IIS6 Dynamic content

Tags: iis, mime-types

After changing `.zip` file mime type on IIS 6 metabase to `application/x-zip`, I can see that `.zip` downloads with a new content type when I download it from a static folder (`/zip`).

But I use an ISAPI extension to download `.zip` files:

> `http://example.com/?downloadname=filename`

Which changes it to `application/x-zip-compressed`.

I have verified it with fiddler and httpanalyzer. A global or targeted mime type change doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to force the mime type change on dynamically generated content such as this?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the mime type from within the ISAP extension by sending the header `Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed`. How to send that header depends a little bit on the language / framework you used to create the ISAPI extension.